# Register a dll in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, dll

I'm trying to register some DLLs for a particular application but having some problems.
The DLLs are stored in the application folder in the D: drive.

I run cmd.exe, go to the D: drive and run regsvr32, but it gives me the error:
"The  was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. This file cannot be registered."

After searching for other solutions, I also tried copying the DLLs into the C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder and running regsvr32 directly there but that didn't work either. It gave me the same error.

I'm not very familiar with Windows Administration, so I may need detailed instructions/explanations. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you need to register the DLLs using regsvr32?  The error message you're showing means the files were not made to be registered.

Comment: @ heavyd - I was specifically asked to register the DLLs...I'm working as an implementing partner to this software company and I am in contact with their technical support engineers. Haven't heard from them in a while so I thought I'll post on some forums for general questions such as this.